# Google Closure Javascript testing, disable autodiscover tests

Tags: unit-testing, google-closure, jsunit

Currently i am implementing the Google closure testing possibilities.
It works as a charm.
I Define the TestCase by hand, and add the test by hand. I also create a separate runner for the tests so I can catch all the results and pass them to another function.
This function sends the results through ajax to PHP so the results can be logged in the database (also works as expected).

The problem however is that because I do this, and I load the page in the browser the tests get executed 2 times (one time because of the auto-discovery and once because i defined it in the testcase.

I would like to disable the auto-discovery, but I don't want to disable the flag in the closure library, this because when the library gets updated we need to reset the flag to false again.

So how can i disable auto-discovery without modifying the code in the closure library?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you look into jsusnit.js, you'll see that `goog.testing.jsunit.AUTO_RUN_ONLOAD = true;` is hard-coded there and you can override this variable only through closure compiler's `define`.

If you don't compile your test code (I don't, because of speed of iteration), the only option seems to change this to false, and redo the change on closure library updates.